# Запуск проекта на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pdo, phpstorm

Предисловие: мне дали на доработку крупный проект (сайт + админка к нему), реализованном на PHP (Yii2 фреймворк). Инструкций и пояснений к сайту нет, только задачи: внедрить карту и Яндекс-метрики. До этого на PHP не программировал никогда. Поставил php, composer (глобально), PHPStorm. В папке проекта сделал composer install, в PHPStorm настроил локальный сервер, работающий на порту 8080.

Моя проблема: не могу запустить ни весь проект целиком, ни перейти на отдельную конкретную страницу.

**Первый путь**

Запуск проекта целиком осуществляю так: запускаю сервер на верхней панели PHPStorm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в браузере перехожу по:

> http://localhost:8080

На странице получаю: `An internal server error occurred`.

А в логе сервера несколько ошибок типа:

```
PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed...in ..\CurrentProject\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:705
```

Сайт взаимодействует с базой данных MySQL и в конфигах для подключений, насколько я понял, всё прописано: строка, учётка и пр. параметры. Так что же вызывает ошибку? Может, я пропустил какой-то этап подготовки и настройки проекта? Я понимаю, что, возможно, глупый вопрос, но у меня нет полного понимания происходящего, поясните, пожалуйста.

**Второй путь**

Поскольку мои задачи относительно простые (карта и метрики), я решил, что можно ограничиться запуском отдельных страниц, а не запуском всего проекта, и таким образом выполнить задачу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В проекте страницы расположены в ..\CurrentProject\frontend\views\site.
На открывшейся странице вместо выполненного кода получаю:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'frontend\models\DefaultContent' not found.
```

И так абсолютно с каждой страницей. Проблема в том, что класс этот есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут не так? Как запустить нормально?

И ещё один момент: при запуске отдельной страницы, описанном в пункте 2, браузер открывает адрес:

> http://localhost:63342/...

Почему порт именно такой, ведь я настраивал сервер на 8080?
Попытавшись понять всё это, я только больше запутался, сейчас просто каша в голове. Объясните, пожалуйста, детально и издалека, что происходит в проекте и как понимать описанные выше моменты, в чём мои ошибки? Очень прошу. Задачи мне нужно эти выполнить обязательно.

Любой код предоставлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю Вам нужно действовать по первому пути, однако необходимо убедиться что на вашей машине запущен сервер базы данных MySQL и доступна по адресу хост:порт указанные в коннектах Вашего проекта, для этого можно использовать команду ping(Windows). Если сервер не доступен значит вам нужно его запустить и настроит на необходимый порт.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, действительно, дело было в отсутствии локальной базы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте устоновить лакальный сервер не используя PHPStorm

для этого есть уже готовые решения к примеру OpenServer

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: у меня нету  пятьдесят баллов репутации